# How to solve sqlite_rtree_geometry_callback error?

Tags: qgis, error, sqlite

I have just installed qgis 1.8 and it show error message

> the procedure entry point sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library sqlite3.dll

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an old sqlite (or without rtree support), so try getting a newer one.

See [this bug report](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/305) for details.